# Concatenate nested dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary.

`sample = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': {}, 'e': {}}, 'f': {}}}}`

I want to print like given below in python.

```
a
a.b
a.b.c
a.b.c.d
a.b.c.e
a.b.f
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a job for a recursive function.

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck at? What did you research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may iterate over the `dict`, and if some values are `dict` too, then concat with the recursive call on them

```
def recurs_print(values):
    results = list(values)
    for key, vals in values.items():
        if isinstance(vals, dict):
            for x in recurs_print(vals):
                results.append(f"{key}.{x}")
    return results


print(recurs_print({'a': 5}))  # ['a']
print(recurs_print({'a': {'b': 6}}))  # ['a']
sample = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': {}, 'e': {}}, 'f': {}}}}
print(recurs_print(sample))  # ['a', 'a.b', 'a.b.c', 'a.b.f', 'a.b.c.d', 'a.b.c.e']
```

To get a *in-order* traversal

```
def recurs_print(values):
    results = []
    for key, vals in values.items():
        results.append(key)                   # <<
        if isinstance(vals, dict):
            for x in recurs_print(vals):
                results.append(f"{key}.{x}")
    return results

['a', 'a.b', 'a.b.c', 'a.b.c.d', 'a.b.c.e', 'a.b.f']
```

Comment: what about `"a.b.f"` for the last example

Comment: @MustafaAydın don't you see it in the list ?

Comment: oh, so sorry I thought it would be at the end `:)`. ++

Comment: I didn't think of "for x in recurs_print(vals):". That was amazing.